# Identify Japanese Font?

Tags: font-identification, japanese

Can anyone help me identify the Japanese font in this picture?

[image]

I have tried several font identification services, but they don't seem to recognize Japanese symbols.

Comment: I can't post the Japanese equivalent here, but the phrase that is represented in the image above is "supersonic speed".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like [ラインG](http://vdl.co.jp/font/lineg.html) from 視覚デザイン研究所, manually kerned and obliqued (Japanese typography doesn't have the notion of oblique or italic as in Latin letters).

[image]

<sup>(sample image using ラインG DemiBold)</sup>